# Is this a postgresql bug? Only one row can not query by equal but can query by like

Tags: postgresql

i have a table,only one row in this table can not query by equal query,but can query by like (not incloud %).

postgresql server version:90513

```sql
# select id,external_id,username,external_id from users where username = 'oFIC94vdidrrKHpi5lc1_2Ibv-OA';
 id | external_id | username | external_id 
----+-------------+----------+-------------
(0 rows)

# select id,external_id,username,external_id from users where username like 'oFIC94vdidrrKHpi5lc1_2Ibv-OA';
                  id                  |         external_id          |           username           |         external_id          
--------------------------------------+------------------------------+------------------------------+------------------------------
 61ebea19-74f5-4713-9a30-63eb5af8ac8f | oFIC94vdidrrKHpi5lc1_2Ibv-OA | oFIC94vdidrrKHpi5lc1_2Ibv-OA | oFIC94vdidrrKHpi5lc1_2Ibv-OA
(1 row)
```

if i dump this table and restore it,it will be fixed. by why.

it is a postgresql bug? how can i workaround it. I've met twice.

Answer (score 3):

Do you have an index on this table? If yes, this appears like corrupted index - PostgreSQL uses index in first case, and if the index is corrupt it might return no result.

This is usually bug, either software one or hardware (data loss on power loss, or any memory issues). Try dropping and recreating index, or rebuilding it with https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/sql-reindex.html

Comment: yes it is a corrupted index bug. i rebuild index fixed it.

Comment: It could be a bug in the PostgreSQL code base, or it could be faulty hardware. Make sure you keep a history of regular (working and tested) backups while you test and figure out which. The standard btree index code will be used by millions of PostgreSQL users but your hardware is only used by you, so I would suspect the hardware first.

Comment: O man... I was looking for hours on google and no info about that. Probably still relevant in 2022.